# handling/manipulate/ transform array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this following array :

```
$myarray = array(
"key_x_1"=>"A",
"key_x_2"=>"B",
"key_x_3"=>"C",
"key_x_4"=>"A",
"key_y_1"=>"10",
"key_y_2"=>"10",
"key_y_3"=>"15",
"key_y_4"=>"20"
);
```

I want to create a new array like this :

```
 $mynewarray = array(
"A"=>array(10,20),
"B"=>array(10),
"C"=>array(15)
);
```

Is it possible ? How can i do this ?

Comment: In the second array ($mynewarray), keys are unique values from values from the first array that contain Key_x. The relation between key_x and key_y are the numbers in key name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your logic, but:

```
$i=1;
while($i<count($myarray)) {
  if(isset($myarray['key_x'.$i]) && isset($myarray['key_y'.$i])) {
    $mynewarray[$myarray['key_x'.$i]][]=$myarray['key_y'.$i];
    ++$i;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: this works, but to follow his code it should be `isset($myarray['key_x_'.$i]) && isset($myarray['key_y_'.$i])`